# Apple Push Notification Service idle timeout

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone know what the timeout is for an idle connection to Apple's Push Notification Server (APNS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Internal testing:

- Any SSL connection seems to be closed right way if no push sending.
- After established the connection and send one validate push over
  APNS, the socket doesn't seem to time out (tested for 24 hours)

Still looking for an official answer or documentation, but this works for me.

Comment: It does not disconnect if no push is sent immediately.